# How to stop specific dhcp interfaces from adding a gateway to my routing table in linux (RPi)?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, raspberry-pi

I've been setting up a VPN server on my Raspberry Pi 3 (latest Noobs) which has worked wonderfully.  The VPN creates an extra interface called vpn_vpn and my normal internet is on wlan0 or sometimes eth0.  My problem comes from the fact that in order for me to get the Pi to have internet access I end up having to remove the gateway that is automatically added whenever vpn_vpn goes up or down (ifup/ifdown).  *I'm fine with removing this gateway as I don't want the internet going through the vpn which doesn't have internet access.*  The command I use for removing this gateway is: `sudo ip route del default via 192.168.30.1` .  I know that the gateway I am trying to remove is always 192.168.30.1 because that is a setting I have made for the VPN.  NOTE: The VPN also includes a dhcp server.

How do I prevent this gateway from even being added when the interface comes up?

Best case, I would like to avoid adding the gateway during `ifup vpn_vpn` but still have automatic adding for all other interfaces.  I require this because I want to maintain the ability to have the pi work on different networks without hard coding for eth0 or wlan0 please.

I'm fairly sure it has to do with dhclient somehow though *I don't know much about dhclient.*

I haven't modified resolv.conf or dhclient.conf but I have them below because I have a feeling they may need editing or provide clues.

## /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.30.1
nameserver 10.0.11.66
```

## /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#       dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#       dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other solutions that might work depending on your setup.

If you know that `ifup` is being used to bring up your VPN interface `vpn_vpn` add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` to change the default route (or any other):

```
iface vpn_vpn inet dhcp
  post-up sleep 6; ip route del default; ip route add default via <gateway_ip>
```

Depending on how long it takes for your DHCP negotiation and/or the routing setup of the VPN, you may have to increase the timeout in the first post-up command `post-up sleep 6`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have finally come up with an answer.  I'd still be happy to hear if anyone comes up with another solution that might work.

I'm testing this solution now:

## bash script

```
echo "script \"/etc/dhcp/dhclient-script\";" | sudo tee -a /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

echo "#!/bin/sh
case \$interface in
vpn_vpn)
    unset \$new_routers
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac" | sudo tee /etc/dhcp/dhclient-script
sudo chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient-script
```